# Only allow authorized AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Simplified: In my JS/PHP app I have a button. When a user clicks on the button he gets 1 point which is saved via jQuery AJAX/PHP in a database.

Of course the user now can call the script that makes the AJAX request without clicking the button. Is there any best-practice to avoid that?

I am using AJAx because I don't want the page to reload.

Update:
There are many other options how a user can earn points. Idealy I would have a JS function add_points(points) that adds the points for the user. But I know that anyone can write a script to call this function automaticly. I guess the only way is to generate a hash vor every possible point-earn action and submit this hash with the AJAX request.

Comment: You need to secure on server side.

Comment: How do you differentiate between an authorized ajax request and a not authorized ajax request? You can take a few measures on the button itself to see where the click occred within the button to ensure that the event x/y is within an acceptable range, then you can take that x/y and see how many happened at the same exact location. if 10k happened at exactly 5,5, it's a good chance that was programmatically done rather than manually. However, none of this stops the user from sending the ajax request themselves. This is an unfortunate downside to most of the html/js based games. Easily cheated.

Comment: All you can really do is recognize patterns and act upon them.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is to generate a hash and check if that hash is new or no used in the last day for example.. making sure that the user has to get a new hash in order to press the button.

Comment: I thought about this and it is probalby the safest way...maybe there is some easier way...

Answer (score 1):

If the user is allowed to click as many times as she wants, there's no real way to prevent doing it automatically. If she's only supposed to click once (like upvoting on stackoverflow), the code your server uses to update the value should automatically confirm that she hasn't clicked it before i.e. check the database.

Comment: Then there is your issue. I could then write any browser script I want to automatically send the request whenever I want.

Comment: Exactly thats the problem thst I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm saying it's unavoidable in your current system. There's no way to securely differentiate between a legitimate button click and an automatic script. Only thing you can maybe do is limit the frequency by using code on the server side to check how long ago the last request was sent.

Comment: @wavemode: Limiting frequency is *not* the only way to prevent vote fraud, and indeed is easily foiled by very simple scripts (eg written with AutoHotKey) that click every N minutes.  The only way to properly solve this is to have an audit trail as outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here */
    die($content);
}
```

Comment: And if the user just calls the function that makes the ajax request, or the user adds that header himself?

Comment: And if the user uses the Developer Tools to simply allow the button to be clickable again, this helps how?

Comment: @EricJ. This is not the question asked. I just answered the question, of course he have to use tokens to handle with security problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need an audit trail to properly solve this problem

Set the status "user clicked the button" rather than "user gets 1 point", and calculate the user's score as the sum of all actions that assign points.  That is the basic approach used by Stack Overflow.

That way, you have an accounting record of how user's got their points, and you can implement business rules like "only allow setting status user clicked the button once"

The way you currently do it, there is no audit trail and indeed you have no way of knowing *why* users have the score they do.

Comment: Still, the server cannot distinguish between the actions "user clicked the button" and "script sent button click".

Comment: @Bergi: No, but the server can record in a database "this user received credit for clicking this button, no matter how that action was actually achieved" and only give credit once.  If you cannot get extra points by scripting actions, there is no incentive to script them.